# How can I delete an id-less entity in Orion?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Question title pretty much self explanatory. It **is** possible to create an id-less entity in Orion. An `id = .*` query returns normally as an id-less, although existing entity. But how can someone delete that entity? This request didn't work obviously:

```
{
  "contextElements": [
   {
      "type": "",
      "isPattern": "false",
      "id": ""
    }
  ],
  "updateAction": "DELETE"
}
```

This is the returned query:

```
{
            "contextElement": {
                "type": "",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "id": "",
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "temp",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "value": "15"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "pressure",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "value": "720"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200",
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
```

Comment: how did you exactly create an id-less entity? If I try to do that with an updateContext I get *Bad Request, empty Id*.

Comment: Sadly I cannot recall the way I did it, so it's impossible to repeat it. And i didn't mess with mongo. It's a 100% legit response by an orion fiware-lab instance. Here: I added a public IP. The database is only for testing, so you can mess with it if you want: 83.212.238.115:1026 . Get the response and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/828) (now fixed) in Orion that seems to be causing your issue. Basically Orion interprets the final "/" at the end of an URL as an empty element.

For example (as documented in the issue):

- v1/contextEntityTypes queries for all types, while
- v1/contextEntityTypes/ queries only for the empty type

In your particular case, something similar happens with some REST operations. If you do a **GET /v1/contextEntities** you will see all entities, including the empty-id one. You can query that particular entity with **GET /v1/contextEntity/** (note the final "/").

And then, the DELETE method doesn't seem to use the same pattern. So if you do **DELETE /v1/contextEntity/** You get a *No context element found*.

So, basically, this is another manifestation of a known bug.